# gvim: switching tabs with keyboard

Tags: vim

I can't seem to find a predefined keyboard shortcut for switching between open tabs in Gvim. What is it, and if there is none, how can I define one?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use `gt` and `gT` commands.

`:tabn` and `:tabp` also work.

Read `:help gt` and read that section completely. There are many useful commands explained there.

Comment: Help is powerful stuff indeed

Comment: If I know that the command is `gt` it is easy to use the help. But how can I find a suitable command to "open a new tab" using Vim's help? `:help tab` doesn't help...

Comment: @SebastianG Use `:helpgrep` to search for text in help files with a regular expression. For this particular problem, I would have used `:helpgrep \<next\ tab\>`. For your particular problem of opening a new tab, I would use `:helpgrep \<new\ tab\>`. See `:help help` to see the various ways `help` can help you.

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer i think you're looking for `:tabnew`

Answer (score 28):

Press `gt` to switch tabs. Also - `1gt` `2gt` to open 1st, 2nd... tab.

Comment: I usually have just two tabs (code, test). So this is the fastest for me.

Answer (score 19):

I have these mappings in my vimrc:

```
map <C-Left> <Esc>:tabprev<CR>
map <C-Right> <Esc>:tabnext<CR>
map <C-n> <Esc>:tabnew
```

I'm by no means a pro vim'er, but it works for me so I thought I'd share :) Control+Right for next tab, Control+Left for previous, Control+n to open a new tab (left out the  so you can specify the path to open in the new tab).

Comment: I like this. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: For me `<C-Left>` is the same as `C-<PageUp>` :)

Comment: Mac users: you may need to disable the default Mission Control spaces keyboard shortcuts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719135/how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-mac-os-x#answer-15719195

Answer (score 13):

```
C-<PageUp>
C-<PageDown>
```

These are predefined, altaught not very practical, as on most keyboards Page keys are placed in the corners, far from 'natural' hands position.

Comment: I use xfce4-terminal which has C-<PageUp/PageDown> defined to switch the terminal tabs. Also not very practicable.