# What do escaped angle brackets do in a vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim

In [gvim: switching tabs with keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832364/gvim-switching-tabs-with-keyboard), Susam Pal gives an example usage of vim's `helpgrep` as:

```
:helpgrep \<next\ tab\>
```

My question is what exactly do the escaped angle brackets accomplish? How does this differ from `:helpgrep next\ tab` or `:helpgrep next tab`?

Comment: Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: @IngoKarkat This is what I ended up doing after starting to ask the question (and why I answered my own question). Much more efficient way of getting answer :-) (no offense SO).

Comment: @IngoKarkat I believe SO wants to be the definitive repository for Q&A, a simple RTFM is not sufficient criticism

Answer (score 5):

The special regular expression atoms `\<` and `\>` assert a *(key)word boundary*, what is frequently done with `\b` in other regular expression dialects.

Without it, `next tab` (no need to escape the space character BTW.) would also match inside `nonext tabbing`. As you often want to search for the whole word, not occurrences inside other words, this restricts the matches. (The `*` command does this for you, too.)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so a quick `:help regexp` and `/\\<` brought me to the answer:

```
      ordinary atom ~
      magic   nomagic   matches ~
...

|/\<|   \<  \<  beginning of a word |/zero-width|
|/\>|   \>  \>  end of a word |/zero-width|
```

Hopefully this is useful for someone...

Comment: You mean `/\\<`, not `/\<`? Also, note that you can get more info on `\<` by following the tag at the beginning of the line (place your cursor over the `|/\<|` and press `<C-]>`). Or you can directly do `:help \<`.

Comment: @Nikita Thanks for the fix and great additional information.